# Need help writing a Python script that will input a sentence and count the number of words it contains

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def main():

  p =input("Enter your sentence: ")

  words = p.split()

  wordCount = len(words)

  print ("The word count is:", wordCount)

main()
```

I get the read out:

Enter your sentence: Hello world
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python27/idk.py", line 11, in  main() File "C:/Python27/idk.py", line 3, in main p =input("Enter your sentence: ") File "", line 1 Hello world ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
What am i doing wrong? D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).  The `input` function tries to evaluate the given input as a python command.

Try using `raw_input` instead, which returns the input as a string.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You tagged Python 2.7, so I am assuming you are using 2.7. If that is the case, you want to use `raw_input()` to take string input, not `input()`. In Python 3, `raw_input` is replaced by `input()` function, but in Python 2, the `input()` function takes input literally, not as a string.

```
def main():

  p = raw_input("Enter your sentence: ") # raw_input() function

  words = p.split()

  wordCount = len(words)

  print ("The word count is:", wordCount)

main()
```

Just an addition, if you wanted the input to be an integer, you can still use the `raw_input()` function. Just `int()` it! `numinput = int(raw_input('Enter a number'))`